# Visualforce: Render only if value is not null throws exception

Tags: html, salesforce, apex, visualforce

I'm building a visualforce page where I have a apex:datatable with several columns.

Now I want the column "Discount" only to be shown when its values are not null and >0.

My Code is as following:

```
<apex:dataTable width="100%" value="{!Opportunity.OpportunityLineItems}" var="oli">
                            <apex:column width="50%" headerClass="tableheaderleft"  styleClass="tablebodyleft">
                                <apex:facet name="header">Bezeichnung</apex:facet>
                                <apex:OutputField value="{!oli.Name}"/>
                             </apex:column>
                            <apex:column width="{!If(oli.Discount!=null,If((oli.Discount>0),"10%","10%"),"10%")}" headerClass="tableheadercenter" footerClass="tablefootercenter" styleClass="tablebodycenter">
                                <apex:facet name="header">Anzahl</apex:facet>
                                <apex:OutputField value="{!oli.Quantity}"/>
                                <apex:facet name="footer"></apex:facet>
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column width="20%" headerClass="tableheaderright"  styleClass="tablebodyright">
                                <apex:facet name="header">Einzelbetrag</apex:facet>
                                <apex:OutputField value="{!oli.UnitPrice}"/>
                                <apex:facet name="footer"></apex:facet>
                            </apex:column>
                            
                         
                           <apex:column  rendered="{!If(oli.Discount!=null,(oli.Discount>0),false)}" headerClass="tableheadercenter" footerClass="tablefootercenter" styleClass="tablebodycenter">
                                <apex:facet name="header">Rabatt</apex:facet>
                                <apex:OutputField value="{!oli.Discount}"/>
                                <apex:facet name="footer"></apex:facet>
                            </apex:column>  
                            
                            <apex:column width="20%" headerClass="tableheaderright"  styleClass="tablebodyright">
                                <apex:facet name="header">Gesamtbetrag</apex:facet>
                                <apex:OutputField value="{!oli.TotalPrice}"/>
                                <apex:facet name="footer"></apex:facet>
                            </apex:column>                                                                                            
                        </apex:dataTable>
```

But I always get the following exception:

javax.faces.FacesException: core.apexpages.exceptions.ApexPagesDeveloperException: Incorrect argumenttype for operator '>'.

Does anybody know why this exception occures? Could it occur because Discount returns a percentage value?

Many Thanks!

Comment: you want column header (& whole column) show only when all rows have discount > 0? At the moment SF decides what to do with header "oli" might not exist yet, you aren't in the rows loop so to speak. See if you can do the condition as `{!Opportunity.OpportunityLineItems[0].Discount > 0}?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I Only want to show the whole column if at least one row has a value.
I tried your solution and this error occurs: The value "null" isnt allowed for operator '>'
When I render the page in preview mode everything works fine. Only when I add an ID to the URL to fill in values the error occus..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clarified in comments "*Only want to show the whole column if at least one row has a value*".

Do you have a Discount-related [rollup summary](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&type=5) field from Opp Line Item to Opp? You could do something like `rendered="{!Opportunity.DiscountLinesCount__c > 0}"` or `{!Opportunity.TotalDiscount__c > 0}`.

If you'd have apex controller (or extension) for it you could check the lines and set some boolean flag and then render based on that. That' be the official way.

Unofficial you could loop through line items before your dataTable, abusing the `<apex:variable>` tag. It's bit of hack but it'd work without any apex. Check my answer to this question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/193169/799

Something like this. Didn't try to run it but should give you idea.

```
<apex:variable var="hasDiscountLines" value="{!false}" />
<apex:repeat value="{!Opportunity.OpportunityLineItems}" var="oli">
    <apex:variable var="hasDiscountLines" value="{!hasDiscountLines || oli.Discount != null}" />
</apex:repeat>

(...)
<apex:dataTable width="100%" value="{!Opportunity.OpportunityLineItems}" var="oli">
    <apex:column  rendered="{!hasDiscountLines}">
    (...)
</apex:dataTable>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! {!Opportunity.TotalDiscount__c > 0} solved my problem! Don't really know why but I tried several If-statements before which all didnt work. I think TotalDiscount is working bc of different field type. No matter why, its working fine!

Comment: Hm. Rollup of numeric/currency field would also be numeric/currency, you'd need extra conversions if discount was text, picklist, whatever. Weird. Well, thx for accepting, happy I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You're having double quotes inside the double quotes.You can use single quotes instead.

E.g.

```html
<apex:column width="{!If(oli.Discount!=null,If((oli.Discount>0),'10%','10%'),'10%')}" headerClass="tableheadercenter" footerClass="tablefootercenter" styleClass="tablebodycenter">
    <apex:facet name="header">Anzahl</apex:facet>
    <apex:OutputField value="{!oli.Quantity}"/>
    <apex:facet name="footer"></apex:facet>
</apex:column>
```

Independent example -

```html
<apex:page>    
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="{! if(true == true, '300%', '200%') }" height="300" style="border:1px solid">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My main problem is, that I want to set the rendered attribute in the "Rabatt" column with an if statement, depending if Discount has a value or not. But every solution I tried does not hide the column.
Do you have a tip for the correct if statement?

Comment: simplest way to hide is through css like you used for width. `class="{! IF(true==true, 'display:none;' : 'display:block;' }"`